# Calculate definite integral using the definition (Riemann Sum)

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I would like to know how to use the Riemann Sum (With Unequal width) to calculate $\displaystyle f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ from $[1,2]$

I know how to calculate it when the interval starts with 0, for example [0,1], I will do the following way:

- $\displaystyle c_i = \frac{i^2}{n^2}$ and $\displaystyle \Delta x_i = \frac{i^2}{n^2}-\frac{(i-1)^2}{n^2}=\frac{2i-1}{n^2}$
- $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^nf(c_i)\Delta x_i = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n = \sqrt{\frac{i^2}{n^2}}\left(\frac{2i-1}{n^2} \right) = \frac{2}{3}$

I understand that by choosing a partition of $\displaystyle\frac{i^2}{n^2}$, it will facilitate our calculation of summation because we have the following formula

- $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

However, if the partition starts with 1 or other numbers, we would have something like $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{1+\frac{i^2}{n^2}}$ which we don't have a directly formula to use.

Is it possible for me to do such Riemann Sum ($\displaystyle\sqrt{x}$ when interval doesn't start with 0) with what I have learned from First Year Calculus in university?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two potential approaches:

1. Try computing both integrals between $[0, 2]$ and $[0, 1)$, and subtract afterwards.
2. If you want to stick to a partition of $[1, 2]$ you could still make the partition follow the same pattern. Try $\frac{i^2}{n^2}$ for $i$ going from $n$ to $\sqrt{2}n$, for example.

Comment: So you mean $\sum_{i=n}^{\sqrt{2}n}$? May I ask what is reason for you to choose this one? And doesn't all the summation formula starts with i=1 to n

Comment: The idea is the same as your original approach, i.e. choosing the rational squares. But in this case I choose them in the interval $[1, 2]$. In general calculating integrals as Riemann sums is very tricky.

Comment: Okay. I understand, thank you for your help! I will also try to ask professor if such question would be possible because surely calculating anti-derivative would be the easiest approach

Comment: The $i$ is really just an index, it can start and stop wherever you like. The only bit of cheating is that $\sqrt{2}n$ is not an integer, so you have to "omit" an ever shrinking rectangle between ${floor}(\sqrt2n)^2/n^2$ and 2.

Comment: Yes yes I can understand! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Let $$c_i=\left(1+ \frac{(\sqrt2-1)i}{n}\right)^2$$

Hence,
\begin{align}\Delta x_i&=\left(1+ \frac{(\sqrt2-1)i}{n}\right)^2-\left(1+ \frac{(\sqrt2-1)(i-1)}{n}\right)^2\\
&=\left( 2+\frac{(\sqrt2-1)(2i-1)}{n}\right)\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{n} \right)\end{align}

and the integral is

\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n f(c_i) \Delta x_i &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \left(1+ \frac{(\sqrt2-1)i}{n}\right)\left( 2+\frac{(\sqrt2-1)(2i-1)}{n}\right)\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{n} \right) \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt2-1}{n^3}  \sum_{i=1}^n [n+(\sqrt2-1)i][2n+(\sqrt2-1)(2i-1)] \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt2-1}{n^3} \sum_{i=1}^n(2n^2+n(\sqrt2-1)(2i-1)+2(\sqrt2-1)in + (\sqrt2-1)^2i(2i-1))\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt2-1}{n^3}\left(2n^3 +n \sum_{i=1}^n 4(\sqrt2-1)i + 2\sum_{i=1}^n (\sqrt2-1)^2i^2 \right) \\
&=\lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{\sqrt2-1}{n^3} \left(2n^3 + 2n^3(\sqrt2-1)+\frac23(\sqrt2-1)^2n^3 \right) \\
&= (\sqrt2-1)\left(2\sqrt2+ \frac23(3-2\sqrt2) \right) \\
&=  \frac13(\sqrt2-1)(2\sqrt2+6) \\
&= \frac23(\sqrt2-1)(\sqrt2+3) \\
&= \frac23 (2\sqrt2-1)
\end{align}

Comment: Hi! Can I ask you why you choose such specific ci? I understand the reason for ci to be squared, but why $1+\frac{(\sqrt{2}-1)i}{n}$?

Comment: so that $c_i$ would cover the range from $1$ to $2$. If you replace $i$ by $0$, you get $1$, if you replace $i$ by $n$, $c_i$ gives you $2$.

Comment: btw, as a practice, you can try to handle the arbitary case for integration over $[a,b]$, just for fun.